How to store cookies in a variable in citrus framework when doing http().client().receive()
I am writing a citrus test to authenticate to our system under test. This system asks to set some cookies. These cookies are used in further API calls.
I am able to get the cookies in cookies variable.
$(receive()
                 .endpoint(todoClient)
                 .message()
                 .extract(fromHeaders()
                         .expression("Set-Cookie", "${cookies}"))
         );

However cookies are returned as:

PQR=x; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT; secure,XYZ=x;
path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 22:00:00 GMT;
secure,ABCD=5e533b5;path=/; SameSite=None; secure,JKLD=7000c31;
path=/; SameSite=None; secure;

How can I extract only ABCD cookie value from this.
